# How to open a page with Phantomjs without running js or making subsequent requests?

Tags: phantomjs

Is there a way to just load the server generated HTML (without any js or images)?

The [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/open.html) seem a little sparse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strength of PhantomJS is exactly in its ability to emulate a real browser, which opens a page and makes all the subsequent request. If you want just html maybe better use curl or wget?

But nevertheless there is a way not to run js or load images: set corresponding page settings: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html

```
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = false;
page.settings.loadImages = false;
```

Comment: Ah, thats were it is in the docs!. Yes thanks, my use case was just to speed up debugging.